# Viewstate cleared after publish of new code

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Why does asp.net clear my viewstate when I publish new code?
The code is run on `Windows Server 2008 R2` with `.net 4.5.2`.

Is there any way to detect when this happens as I have a page that flips out totally when this happens. (some state is saved, my guess because its a partial postback so items outside the updating `UpdatePanel`s aren't updated).

I checked `IsChildControlStateCleared` and its `false`.

I have also defined a `machineKey` to ensure its not the issue.

Comment: Have you unchecked "Automatically Generate at runtime" in IIS?

Comment: @Matt, if I open the `Machine Key` section for the site in IIS its unchecked. (All 4 checkboxes are)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a hacky solution, on the first page load, i add a item to the `ViewState`, on each `IsInAsyncPostBack` i check if that item is still there if not i reload the page with a `Redirect`.

I would prefer a better solution or just get a explanation on why its clearing the `ViewState`.

Answer (score -1):

Viewstate is clearing after 10 postbacks of the page

Comment: What on earth are you trying to say with this Answer?